# Recurrence relation for number of indecomposable permutations

Tags: permutations, recurrence-relations

> We say the permutation $\sigma = a_1,..., a_n \in S_n$ is indecomposable if
>   ${a_1 , \dots ,a_j} \neq [j] ,\forall j<n$. Let $f(n)$ be the count of the indecomposable permutations in $S_n$.
>
> Show that,
>
> $(a)$ $\sum_{j=1}^n f(j)(n-j)! = n!$ and $n\geq 1$
>
> $(b)$ $(\sum_{n\geq1}f(n)t^n)(\sum_{n\geq0}n!t^n)=(\sum_{n\geq1}n!t^n)-1$

to i) let $A_i$ be the set of all perms $\sigma \in S_n$ with $\sigma[i]=[i]$ and $\sigma \in S_n$ with $\sigma[j]\neq[j]$

$\Rightarrow S_n = A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \dots \cup A_n$

why should this be $f(i)(n-i)$ ?

to ii) no idea :-(

Comment: What is the quantity on the right hand side of i) ?

Comment: the right side is = n!

Answer (score 3):

For the first part, we just double count the number of permutations of $[n]$. The right hand side is just the number of permutations, $n!$. On the left hand side, we group permutations based on the first index $i$ such that $a_1\dots a_i=[i]$. If the *first* such index is $i$, then there are $f(i)$ choices for the first $i$ letters, and then we just need an arbitrary permutation of $\{i+1,\dots,n\}$ to finish our permutation. So for a given $i$, there are $f(i)(n-i)!$ such permutations. Summing over all possible indices gives the desired result.

For the second part, read about multiplying power series (here is a link if you need: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series#Multiplication_and_division), and then use the first part.