# Number of permutations $(p_1,\dots,p_6)$ of $\{1,\dots,6\}$ such that for any $1\le k\le5,(p_1,\dots,p_k)$ is not a permutation of $\{1,\dots,k\}$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, contest-math

**Problem** (INMO 1992 problem #4)

Find the number of permutations $(p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4,p_5,p_6)$ of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ such that for any $k$ such that $1 \le k \le 5,$ $(p_1,...,p_k)$ does not form a permutation of $\{1,2,....k\}$

**My attempt**

I have done a very ugly approach i.e doing case work and counting each case separately. After a long time after going through many mistakes,over countings, i have reached the correct answer $461$.

Initially, i have tried to come up with a recursive relation but i ended up missing too many cases.

**Question**

Since this an olympiad there must be a nicer and elegant solution. Can anybody share their insights to this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are [indecomposable permutations](https://oeis.org/A003319). If $f(n)$ is the number of indecomposable permutations of $[n]=\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$ then recurrence relation $$n!=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{f(i)(n-i)!}$$ holds. This can be proven by [double counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_counting_(proof_technique)) the number of permutations of $[n].$ The left side is the standard formula. The right side does casework on the leftmost index $i$ at which the first $i$ numbers in a permutation of $[n]$ forms the set $[i].$ We get $f(i)$ from the fact that for all lower indices $j<i,$ the first $j$ numbers in the permutation do not form $[j],$ and $(n-i)!$ is the number of ways of permuting the higher indices $j>i.$ Such an index must exist by the [well-ordering principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_principle) since all $n$ numbers form the set $[n].$ By repeatedly using the recurrence relation and $f(1)=1,$ we get $$f(6)=461.$$ The recurrence relation is also stated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1253064/recurrence-relation-for-number-of-indecomposable-permutations).

Comment: shouldn't $f(1)$ be $0$? $ [1]={1}$, we can't permute this set to fulfill our requirements.Also please elaborate how you got RHS in detail.I can't make sense of it

Comment: say $i$ is the first index for which $a_1,\cdots,a_i$ is a permutation of $[i]$.Now sum over all possible i.

Comment: @MathematicalCuriosity $f(1)=1$ because the condition is for all $j<i,$ the first $j$ entries of the permutation cannot form $[j].$ But there are no entries before the first one, so the "for all" condition is vacuously fulfilled. For the argument of the right side, what part of the argument are you having trouble with? It's a matter of double counting the number of permutations of $[n].$

Comment: @Favst I got it.Thanks for your response.